Collection being made but when adding nfts to the collection i get 'Program log: Collection Not Found on Metadata'
Error
Error
Proof That the collection exists

What I did: Correctly created a collection.
What was expected: I tried to add a test NFT to the collection, though the collection exists, it says "Collection Not Found on Metadata."
async function createNft(
  metaplex: Metaplex,
  uri: string,
  nftData: NftData,
  collectionMint: PublicKey
): Promise<NftWithToken> {
  const { nft } = await metaplex.nfts().create(
    {
      uri: uri, // metadata URI
      name: nftData.name,
      sellerFeeBasisPoints: nftData.sellerFeeBasisPoints,
      symbol: nftData.symbol,
    },
    { commitment: "finalized" }
  )

  console.log(
    `Token Mint: https://explorer.solana.com/address/${nft.address.toString()}?cluster=devnet`
  )

  // This is what verifies our collection as a Certified Collection
  await metaplex.nfts().verifyCollection({
    mintAddress: nft.mint.address,
    collectionMintAddress: collectionMint,
    isSizedCollection: true,
  })

  return nft
}


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
